# retrieving data from Sqlite database is getting slower at afterTextChanged method in android

Tags: android, sqlite

I have a EditText box.In this text box i used `afterTextChanged(Editable s)` method.
I have a database containing about 60,000 data. My am making a dictionary.
So my aim is that when a user enter any text into the textbox(EditText),it shows the 10 rows into a listview from the database matching with the entered text.

In my mainactivity  i used `afterTextChanged(Editable s)` like

```
        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            mDbHelper.open();

            String ss=s.toString();

             ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> list_of_wordmeanings = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

            Cursor mCursor = mDbHelper.getTestData(ss); // here i got the result from the database

            for (int i = 0; i < mCursor.getCount(); i++) 
            {
                mCursor.moveToPosition(i);                                      

                HashMap<String, String> hm = new HashMap<String, String>();

                    String word = mCursor.getString(0).toString();
                    String meaning = mCursor.getString(1).toString();

                      hm.put("key_word",word);
                      hm.put("key_meaning",meaning);

                      list_of_wordmeanings.add(hm);
            }

                    String[] from = { "key_word","key_meaning" };

                    int[] to = { R.id.txt1,R.id.txt2};

                    SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(getBaseContext(), list_of_wordmeanings, R.layout.list_layout, from, to);

                    listView.setAdapter(adapter);

                    mDbHelper.close();

        }
    });
```

My used function to get the data from database is like that:

```
public Cursor getTestData(String s)
 {
     try
     {

     //String sql ="SELECT * FROM Table1 LIMIT 5";//"SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_REGISTRATION +" WHERE "+ KEY_NAME +" LIKE '"+ s +"%'" ;

         String sql ="SELECT  * FROM dic WHERE english LIKE '"+ s +"%' LIMIT 5" ;

         Cursor mCur = mDb.rawQuery(sql, null);
         if (mCur!=null)
         {
            mCur.moveToNext();
         }
         return mCur;
     }
     catch (SQLException mSQLException) 
     {
         Log.e(TAG, "getTestData >>"+ mSQLException.toString());
         throw mSQLException;
     }
 }
```

Everything is working well but problem is that showing the matching result is very slow.
How can i do it in a faster way??
Can anyone give me proper solution????

Comment: check this link http://www.mysamplecode.com/2012/07/android-listview-cursoradapter-sqlite.html uses cursor adapter which direct binding to database. so check follow this step and check the performance.

Answer (score 0):

Your `afterTextChanged()` method is very inefficient. You could improve it with the following changes:

Don't open and close the database each time the user changes the text(and the `afterTextChanged()` method get's called). So don't do `mDbHelper.open();` every time, do something like this instead:

```
if (!mDbHelper.isDataBaseOpen()) {
    // the database is not open so open it
    mDbHelper.open();// for future text entered the database will be already open  
}
```

You'll then close the database at a later point(like `onPause` of the `Activity`).

There's no reason to extract the data from the `Cursor` and put it in a `HashMap`, a `Cursor` is more efficient and not to mention that this extraction will create hundreds of objects which you should avoid. If you're doing this to use a `SimpleAdapter`, then use the `Cursor` along with a `SimpleCursorAdapter`(or you could make your own adapter).

Don't make a new adapter each time instead reuse the first instance and update only the data of that adapter(followed by a `notifyDataSetChanged()` call).

You shouldn't make database queries on the main UI thread(like you do in the `afterTextChanged()` with the `mDbHelper.getTestData(ss)` call). Also, based on the text entered by the user you could require only one database query. For example if the user enters `a` the `Cursor` will get all rows for that query. But if he enters `ab` then it's safe to assume that the filtered rows will be in the initial set(the `Cursor` returned for `a`) so you could simply look at the `Cursor` data and pick only the values that you need. Have a look at [`CursorWrapper`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/CursorWrapper.html) for this.